# Getting layer from multivalue input in python toolbox

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, multi-values

```
param5 = arcpy.Parameter(
        name="C",
        displayName="C",
        direction="Input",
        datatype="DEFeatureClass",
        parameterType="Required",
        multiValue=True)

    parameters = [param0, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5]

    return parameters
```

[image]

And now I want to get each of layer from param5. I must do this such as here?

`c = parameters[5]
 c1 = c[0].valueAsText
 c2 = c[1].valueAsText`

Multivalue parameter is a list? What is the way that get each of leyer? If I would like to do Merge (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/merge.htm). That's enough pass parameters[5] as first argument to Merge_management??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily print the contents of the `c` by using `arcpy.AddMessage(c)` in your `execute` method. This will show up `fc1path;fc2path` text in the dialog box window. That is, the multivalues are semicolon delimited.

You can pass the parameter as is to any geoprocessing tool that can work with [multivalues](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/working-with-multivalue-inputs.htm) such as `Merge`. If you want to do finer processing of each input feature class, you could use Python `split()` method to get each of the path:

```
s = 'path1;path2;path3'
s.split(';')
['path1', 'path2', 'path3']
```

Comment: Now imagine you have someone who likes to use semicolons in layer names like: "US; California; Los Angeles; Roads". The events, characters and firms discussed are fictitious. Any similarity to actual persons, living or dead, or to actual firms, is purely coincidental :)